# Is it possible to take Steam screenshots without using the in-game overlay?

Tags: steam

As the title states. Sometimes running with the steam overlay is a bad idea, but I find myself wanting to put screenshots on my Steam profile, which the built-in game screenshot functionality does not allow me to. Is there a way to accomplish that, be it via a trick, or running the overlay without actually overlaying anything?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Here's a thread from the steam forums](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=3004368) which gives a very roundabout way of taking screenshots without using the steam overlay (I've duplicated what's said there with a few edits as Jonathan Drapeau recommended). Some games just don't work with it. Basically, you have to manually create a remote folder under the appid of the particular game and store screenshots in there.

1. First find the appid of the game. An easy way of doing this is searching for the game in the steam store on store.steampowered.com and noting the number in the URL. [Here's an example using Teslagrad](https://gyazo.com/dd54428f0cc12ccc4e0c1b2f57c68e14)
2. Take your screenshots using <kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>PrtScrn</kbd> (windowed) or <kbd>PrtScrn</kbd> (full desktop) or use Camtasia, FRAPS, etc.
3. Close Steam.
4. Create the App ID folder in the following file path: `Program Files\Steam\userdata\X(number may vary)\760\remote`
5. Create a "`screenshots`" folder inside `249590` (that's the number from the example for Teslagrad yours will vary). Inside `screenshots` create a folder called "`thumbnails`". So now you have: `Program Files\Steam\userdata\X\760\remote\249590\screenshots` & `Program Files\Steam\userdata\X\760\remote\249590\screenshots\thumbnails`
6. Each screenshot is named with the date and a number. Structure is year-month-date: `2015-XX-XX_00001.jpg`.
7. Create the thumbnails for your screens. Thumbnails resolution size is 200x150. The max horizontal resolution is 200 and the max vertical resolutiono is 150. You can scale either way within those bounds as needed (eg. 200x94 or 180x150). Screenshots need a thumbnail. They need to be named with the same file name as the full size screenshot.
8. Open Steam again. Let it synchronise and scan your files. Open your screenshots folder. Voilá! The newly taken screenshots will be there, ready to be uploaded to the cloud so you can carry them everywhere!

Good luck! This steps will be useful for other games that fail to take screenshots or have problems too.

Comment: While the link can answer the question, you should add the needed information for this answer to be useful even if the link dies.

Comment: @m0nde thanks for the great info.  But I hope somebody scripts this process to avoid so much manual steps.

Comment: Damn, this is horribly complex. Really needs an utility program for this, badly.

Comment: @Llamageddon I am working on such program, and it's almost done; I'll squash some bugs and release it soon. Hopefully next week.

Comment: @TranslucentCloud Ah, cool :P

Answer (score 2):

I've tried to automate the process described by m0nde. It requires PowerShell to run, but if you have Windows 7 or newer you have it preinstalled.

Save this as `run.bat`:

```
@powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File main.ps1
```

And this as `main.ps1`:

```
Function Get-VDFContent ([string] $path)
{
  $fileContent = Get-Content $path
  $obj = @{}
  $stack = New-Object System.Collections.Stack

  $group = [regex] '^\s*"([^"]+)"\s*$'
  $keyVal = [regex] '^\s*"([^"]+)"\s*"([^"]+)"\s*$'
  $bracket = $False

  ForEach ($line in $fileContent)
  {
    If ($bracket)
    {
      If ($line -Like "*{*")
      {
        $bracket = $False
      }
    }
    ElseIf (($match = $group.Match($line)) -And $match.Success)
    {
      $obj.($match.Groups[1].Value) = @{}
      $stack.Push($obj)
      $obj = $obj.($match.Groups[1].Value)
      $bracket = $True
    }
    ElseIf (($match = $keyVal.Match($line)) -And $match.Success)
    {
      $obj.($match.Groups[1].Value) = $match.Groups[2].Value
    }
    ElseIf ($line -Like "*}*")
    {
      $obj = $stack.Pop()
    }
    Else
    {
      Throw
    }
  }

  Return $obj
}

Function Create-ScreenshotPath([string] $screenshots, [string] $date, [string] $i)
{
  Return Join-Path $screenshots ($date + ($i.PadLeft(5, "0")) + ".jpg")
}

$steamPath = ""
If (Test-Path "HKCU:\Software\Valve\Steam")
{
  $steamPath = (Get-ItemProperty "HKCU:\Software\Valve\Steam").SteamPath
}
If (-Not $steamPath)
{
  $steamPath = Read-Host 'Enter Steam install folder path (example: "c:/program files (x86)/steam")'
}

$loginUsers = Join-Path $steamPath "config/loginusers.vdf"
$users = (Get-VDFContent $loginUsers).users
$lastUser = ($users.GetEnumerator() | Sort-Object { [int]$_.Value.Timestamp } -Descending)[0].Name
$lastUserShort = $lastUser - 0x110000100000000

$userPath = Join-Path $steamPath ("userdata/" + $lastUserShort)
$localConfig = Join-Path $userPath "/config/localconfig.vdf"
$apps = (Get-VDFContent $localConfig).UserLocalConfigStore.Software.Valve.Steam.apps
$lastPlayed = ($apps.GetEnumerator() | Sort-Object { [int]$_.Value.LastPlayed } -Descending)[0].Name

$screenshots = Join-Path $userPath ("760/remote/" + $lastPlayed + "/screenshots")
$thumbnails = Join-Path $screenshots "thumbnails"
New-Item -Force -ItemType directory -Path $thumbnails >$null

$scriptPath = Split-Path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
$date = Get-Date -Format yyyy-MM-dd_
$i = 1

While (Test-Path (Create-ScreenshotPath $screenshots $date $i)) { $i++ }

$filesToMove = Get-ChildItem $scriptPath -Filter "*.jpg" | % { $_.FullName }

ForEach ($file in $filesToMove)
{
  Move-Item $file (Create-ScreenshotPath $screenshots $date $i)
  $i++
}
```

Now put those files in one directory with screenshots you want to upload and launch `run.bat`. This script finds last logged-in user and last played game so keep it in mind before running.

Comment: Not sure if I know exactly how it's meant to be used - is it meant to be ran after pressing PrintScrn to copy the screen's contents to the clipboard, or..? Also, presume you did try and find a way to make it work 100% automatically for the currently running game, and had no success, right? Well, I don't really imagine there being a way of detecting if steam is running a game.

Comment: @Llamageddon The script in this post only automates steps 4, 5, and 6 of m0nde's answer. You should place it in the same folder you've saved the screenshots you created in step 2. Unfortunately you'll also need to create thumbnails as described in step 7 and manually move them to the thumbnail directory.

Comment: Ouch. Guess that makes it far less practical, still, an upvote for the effort.

Comment: @RossRidge Did you even try m0nde's method? You don't need to create thumbnails nor close Steam (you can even have your game still running), so steps 3, 7 and 8 are not needed. You forgot about step 1, my script also covers that.

Comment: @Llamageddon Just take screenshots using any tool (with saving them to file if you use `PrtScrn`), move them to the same folder as scripts above and launch `run.bat`.

Comment: @PiotrKowalski Yes, I have.

Comment: @RossRidge I meant not stick to it but experiment a bit and skip some steps.

Comment: Again, yes, I have.

Comment: I used this today playing Ultima IV and posting screenshots to my Steam account. That's why I edited it to clarify. I kept Photoshop open and used `PrtScrn` and `ctrl-v` in Photoshop and then saved full resolution in the appropriate folder and then created a max width 200px thumbnail with the same name in the appropriate folder.
The only difficult part, since this was a non-Steam game was to find the AppID. I created a desktop shortcut and saw that it gives the AppID there like this: `steam://rungameid/18270144037962907648`

Answer (score 1):

A small modification to [Piotr Kowalski's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/238288/212957). 
Now it also makes thumbnails for your screenshots.

Take the file from [this gist](https://gist.github.com/artemsmikh/9f949db3b7a89394299d8b3f71e11fd0) or just paste the code into your `main.ps1`

file:

```
# Modified version of @piotr-kowalski's script 
# Now also makes thumbnails for screenshots
# https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/238288/212957
#
# Note:
# This script finds last logged-in user and last played game so keep it in mind before running.
#
# Usage:
# 1) Save this as run.bat:
# @powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File main.ps1
# 2) Download this file
# 3) Put both files in one directory with screenshots you want to upload and launch run.bat.

Function Get-VDFContent ([string] $path)
{
  $fileContent = Get-Content $path
  $obj = @{}
  $stack = New-Object System.Collections.Stack

  $group = [regex] '^\s*"([^"]+)"\s*$'
  $keyVal = [regex] '^\s*"([^"]+)"\s*"([^"]+)"\s*$'
  $bracket = $False

  ForEach ($line in $fileContent)
  {
    If ($bracket)
    {
      If ($line -Like "*{*")
      {
        $bracket = $False
      }
    }
    ElseIf (($match = $group.Match($line)) -And $match.Success)
    {
      $obj.($match.Groups[1].Value) = @{}
      $stack.Push($obj)
      $obj = $obj.($match.Groups[1].Value)
      $bracket = $True
    }
    ElseIf (($match = $keyVal.Match($line)) -And $match.Success)
    {
      $obj.($match.Groups[1].Value) = $match.Groups[2].Value
    }
    ElseIf ($line -Like "*}*")
    {
      $obj = $stack.Pop()
    }
    Else
    {
      Throw
    }
  }

  Return $obj
}

Function Create-ScreenshotPath([string] $screenshots, [string] $date, [string] $i)
{
  Return Join-Path $screenshots ($date + ($i.PadLeft(5, "0")) + ".jpg")
}

Function Save-Thumbnail([string] $imagePath, [string] $pathToSave)
{
  $wia = New-Object -com wia.imagefile
  $wia.LoadFile($imagePath)
  $wip = New-Object -ComObject wia.imageprocess
  $scale = $wip.FilterInfos.Item("Scale").FilterId                    
  $wip.Filters.Add($scale)
  $wip.Filters[1].Properties("MaximumWidth") = 200
  $wip.Filters[1].Properties("MaximumHeight") = 150
  #aspect ratio should be set as false if you want the pics in exact size 
  $wip.Filters[1].Properties("PreserveAspectRatio") = $true
  $wip.Apply($wia) 
  $newimg = $wip.Apply($wia)
  $newimg.SaveFile($pathToSave)
}

$steamPath = ""
If (Test-Path "HKCU:\Software\Valve\Steam")
{
  $steamPath = (Get-ItemProperty "HKCU:\Software\Valve\Steam").SteamPath
}
If (-Not $steamPath)
{
  $steamPath = Read-Host 'Enter Steam install folder path (example: "c:/program files (x86)/steam")'
}

$loginUsers = Join-Path $steamPath "config/loginusers.vdf"
$users = (Get-VDFContent $loginUsers).users
$lastUser = ($users.GetEnumerator() | Sort-Object { [int]$_.Value.Timestamp } -Descending)[0].Name
$lastUserShort = $lastUser - 0x110000100000000

$userPath = Join-Path $steamPath ("userdata/" + $lastUserShort)
$localConfig = Join-Path $userPath "/config/localconfig.vdf"
$apps = (Get-VDFContent $localConfig).UserLocalConfigStore.Software.Valve.Steam.apps
$lastPlayed = ($apps.GetEnumerator() | Sort-Object { [int]$_.Value.LastPlayed } -Descending)[0].Name

$screenshots = Join-Path $userPath ("760/remote/" + $lastPlayed + "/screenshots")
$thumbnails = Join-Path $screenshots "thumbnails"
New-Item -Force -ItemType directory -Path $thumbnails >$null

$scriptPath = Split-Path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
$date = Get-Date -Format yyyy-MM-dd_
$i = 1

While (Test-Path (Create-ScreenshotPath $screenshots $date $i)) { $i++ }

$filesToMove = Get-ChildItem $scriptPath -Filter "*.jpg" | % { $_.FullName }

ForEach ($file in $filesToMove)
{
  $thumbnailPath = (Create-ScreenshotPath $thumbnails $date $i)
  (Save-Thumbnail $file $thumbnailPath)

  Move-Item $file (Create-ScreenshotPath $screenshots $date $i)
  $i++
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **[SteaScree](https://steascree.download/)**. It can upload screenshots from any source to the Steam cloud. This includes sources such as a game's built-in screenshot functionality, or other game screenshot software (e.g. Bandicam, FRAPS, Geforce Experience / Nvidia Ansel, etc.), bypassing the need for the Steam overlay.

> SteaScree is a simple cross-platform open-source utility tool, which
> greatly simplifies the uploading of screenshots to the Steam Cloud,
> which were taken without the use of Steam's in-game overlay. You just
> pick pics, select game and SteaScree will do the rest.
>
> The problem: every Steam user has 20 GB of cloud space specifically
> for a screenshot storing. But not every screenshot can be easily
> uploaded to the Steam Cloud, since the files should have been created
> by Steam in-game overlay, thus have a specific filename, reside in
> specific Steam directories and be registered within a special
> screenshots.vdf file. Steam fails to upload custom screenshots
> returning "Steam Cloud may be temporarily unavailable" error.
> SteaScree resolves this and automates the whole screenshot uploading
> preparation process.
>
> [image: screenshot of SteaScree UI with instructions on how to use]